# What is WCF userPrincipalName value attribute format for using a local account?

Tags: wcf, userprincipal

assuming the local account name is "JohnDoe" & the local machine name is "Development"...

In a clear, unambiguous functional example what should the value for userPrincipalName be?

```
    <identity>
      <userPrincipalName value="WHAT GOES HERE IF USING A LOCAL ACCOUNT?" />
    </identity>
```